# Using Flask Template in CSS <Style> tag

Tags: css, flask

I a currently working on a school project that requires no usage of javascript. I need to build a list of filters where the filter lists are retrieved from sql. My css codes are placed in the style tags
Here's how the original code looked like:

```
#class1.tablefilter:checked ~ table tbody tr.class1 {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Here's how I should edit my code to:

```
#{{distinct[0]}}.tablefilter:checked ~ table tbody tr.{{distinct[0]}} {
    display:table-row;
}
```

However, this is having an error and i believed it is due to {{distinct[0]}}. Is there any way to translate this code or any way to escape from style?

Answer (score 1):

From Django docs regarding [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag)

> Outputs one of the syntax characters used to compose template tags.
>
> Since the template system has no concept of “escaping”, to display one
>   of the bits used in template tags, you must use the {% templatetag %}
>   tag.